# Input Field and Button is not showing in react

Tags: html, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a contact page in portfolio in  which a form will take data(subject,emailid,body) from the user and sends me an email(Using emailJs for this).The problem is that I am not able to display the input and button at all in the portfolio project.The below code is not working in my portfolio project but it is working fine  when I use the same code in another react project.I am using tailwindCSS,is affecting the code some how?

The code for the contact page is :

```
    import { useState } from "react";
    const Form = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [subject, setSubject] = useState("");
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

    return (
        <div>
        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
        <form>
            <label>
            Email:
            <input
                className=""
                type="text"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            </label>
            <br /> <br />
            <label>
            Subject:
            <input
                type="text"
                name="subject"
                value={subject}
                onChange={(e) => setSubject(e.target.value)}
                required
            />
            </label>
            <br /> <br />
            <label>
            Message:
            <textarea
                name="text"
                value={message}
                onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
                required
            ></textarea>
            </label>
            <br /> <br />
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    );
    };

    export default Form;
```

At first ,I thought the code was wrong , but when I tried the same code in another project is working
Please help me solve this issue or tell me what leads to this kind issue.Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any issue in this code, but few things to check -> file name, any errors in console, is it imported correctly ... please add them to see if any is the reason

Comment: there are no errors in the contact page, maybe you could provide more code, like how to use this component.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.The  issue is because of TailwindCSS.I uninstalled it and now it is working properly.